# Ground Water or Well Water? How do I tell?

Tags: water, leak, well

**Problem:**
I have a puddle at the bottom of a tree and shrub covered slope that will not dry.

**Situation:**
My wellhead is above and in-line (i.e. approimately the same distince from the house) with this puddle.  My well depth is 55 feet (16 meters) while my neighbor's in 18 ft (5.5m). This leads me to believe in a high water table.
The puddle is about 20-25 horizontal feet (6-7.5m) away from the well.  Near the wellhead, maybe 2 feet, (.6 meter) is a faucet with a hose bib. 
I do not notice the pump running without the occupants using water.
Even when the rest of the yard is dry and solid, this area is wet and spongy.

How can I tell if this puddle is due to ground water or a leaky water pipe?